# Improve performance of query execution with Date field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

We have Oracle 11G R2 on production environment.

I like to improve performance of 1 query

```
select .... 
  from FORMX 
 where (INF_TYP  =?)
   AND (STATUS IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) 
   AND ((VAL_DAT>=? OR VAL_DAT  IS NULL));
```

Type of `VAL_DAT` column is `DATE`.
Adding index to `VAL_DAT` is not giving visible effect.

Any ideas how it can be tuned or how to change query ?

Edit

We have about 150K records totally in that table (for 1 year of production)
Condition `VAL_DAT is null` is true for about 8% of records.

Type of 'INF_TYP' and 'STATUS' are VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) and VARCHAR2(10 CHAR).

Comment: Not enough information. How large is your table (how many rows, average row space)? What percentage of rows each filter is supposed to return? How many rows have VAL_DAT=null? What is the `clustering_factor` of the index?

Comment: What @Vincent said + what are conditions 1 and 2? What other indexes are already on the table?

Comment: I updated the question.
@Vincent Malgrat I don't know value of clustering_factor at this momment becoues i do not have index right now.

Answer (score 5):

You could try adding a index as follows:

```
create index ...
on           formx ( val_dat, 0)
```

Because 0 is never null, even the null entries of val_dat will be indexed.

If inf_typ is commonly used as a condition along with val_dat then a composite index leading with inf_typ would be a good choice. You'd want inf_type to lead because the predicate on val_dat is a range:

```
create index ...
on           formx ( inf_typ, val_dat)
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done. Didn't know this. Hard to understand though ;)

Comment: Would an index on `(inf_typ, val_dat)` have the same effect?

Comment: It certainly would, if inf_typ is constrained to not null.

Comment: inf_typ is constrained to not null